# Issues when using DATE_DIFF with MAX(DATE)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am working on Google Analytics data in BigQuery and I am trying to calculate the DATE_DIFF between `IF(COUNT(DISTINCT hits.transaction.transactionId) > 0,(MAX(DATE))` and `CURRENT_DATE()` but I am getting the error:

> Error: No matching signature for function IF for argument types: BOOL, STRUCT. Supported signature: IF(BOOL, ANY, ANY) at [12:11]

What does this mean? Do both parts of the `IF` have to be the same type? I've also seem a similar error which suggests that MAX(DATE) is a STRING, so I tried:

`DATE_DIFF(IF(COUNT(DISTINCT hits.transaction.transactionId) > 0, PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d',(MAX(DATE)),CURRENT_DATE())),CURRENT_DATE(),DAY) AS days_since_lst_ord`

But then I get:

> Error: No matching signature for function PARSE_DATE for argument types: STRING, STRING, DATE. Supported signature: PARSE_DATE(STRING, STRING) at [12:66]

Here is my full query:

```
SELECT customDimension.value AS UserID, COUNT(DISTINCT VisitId) AS visits, COUNT(DISTINCT hits.transaction.transactionId) AS orders, IFNULL(SUM(totals.bounces),0) AS bounces, SUM(totals.pageviews) AS pageviews, IFNULL(SUM(hits.transaction.transactionRevenue)/1000000,0) AS revenue,
ROUND(IFNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT hits.transaction.transactionId)/COUNT(DISTINCT VisitId),0),5) AS conversion_rate,
ROUND(IFNULL(SUM(totals.bounces)/COUNT(DISTINCT VisitId),0),5) AS bounce_rate,   ROUND(IFNULL(SUM(hits.transaction.transactionRevenue)/1000000,0)/COUNT(DISTINCT VisitId),2) AS rev_per_visit,
IF(COUNT(DISTINCT hits.transaction.transactionId) > 0,(MAX(DATE)),"unknown") AS last_ord_date,
DATE_DIFF(IF(COUNT(DISTINCT hits.transaction.transactionId) > 0, PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d',(MAX(DATE)),CURRENT_DATE())),CURRENT_DATE(),DAY) AS days_since_lst_ord
FROM `PROJECTNAME.ga_sessions_20*` AS t
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST (hits) AS hits
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(t.customdimensions) AS customDimension
WHERE parse_date('%y%m%d', _table_suffix) between
DATE_sub(current_date(), interval 1 day) and
DATE_sub(current_date(), interval 1 day)
AND customDimension.index = 2
AND customDimension.value NOT LIKE "true"
AND customDimension.value NOT LIKE "false"
AND customDimension.value NOT LIKE "undefined"
AND customDimension.value IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY UserID, hits.eventInfo.eventCategory
Order by orders DESC
```

Comment: Try formatting your query and looking at the result...I think the problem is that you aren't lining up the parentheses where you think they should be. This expression makes no sense, for instance: `PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d',(MAX(DATE)),CURRENT_DATE())`.

Comment: I will try this, but I'm not sure `PARSE_DATE` is even the right approach here. should I not just be able to calculate a `DATE_DIFF` from `MAX(DATE)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you replace `last_ord_date` and `days_since_lst_ord` with this?

```
IF(COUNT(DISTINCT hits.transaction.transactionId) > 0, (MAX(DATE)) ,"unknown") AS last_ord_date,

DATE_DIFF(IF(COUNT(DISTINCT hits.transaction.transactionId) > 0, PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d',(MAX(DATE))) , CURRENT_DATE())
    ,CURRENT_DATE()
    ,DAY) AS days_since_lst_ord
```

Comment: Hi, this returns > Error: Could not cast literal "unknown" to type DATE at [10:89]

Comment: could you also try my last update? it seems like parentheses problem.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Error: No matching signature for function IF for argument types: BOOL, STRUCT. 
> Supported signature: IF(BOOL, ANY, ANY) at [12:11]
> ```
>
> What does this mean? Do both parts of the IF have to be the same type?

Both true_result and else_result expressions must be coercible to a common supertype.

As an example, below will not work

```
SELECT IF(true, 1, '1.1')
```

whereas this one  - will work perfectly

```
SELECT IF(true, 1, 1.1)
```

Please note, result of last statement will be 1.0 (FLOAT)

Meantime, if you run below - result will be 1 (INTEGER)

```
SELECT IF(true, 1, 2)
```

See more about [Coercion](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#coercion)